# Applying if statements to replace data in 'Column Y' corresponding to different rows in 'Column X'

Tags: python, pandas

Below is a slice of data I am working on and there are thousands of rows and other columns. I have to change the values in 'Column Y' according to the below conditions in 'Column X'.

If Column X is "FIRST" :

cell#1 = epithelial

cell#2 = nerve

If Column X is "SECOND":

cell#1 = endothelial

cell#2 = muscle

Dataframe:

```
 Column X            Column Y        
    FIRST               cell#1
    FIRST               A
    FIRST               cell#2
    FIRST               C
    SECOND              N
    SECOND              V
    SECOND              cell#1
    SECOND              cell#2
```

Code:

```
for row in df['Column X']:
    if row == "FIRST":
        df.loc[(df['Column Y']== "cell#1"), 'Column Y'] = "epithelial"
        df.loc[(df['Column Y']== "cell#2"), 'Column Y'] = "nerve"
    elif row == "SECOND":
        df.loc[(df['Column Y']== "cell#1"), 'Column Y'] = "endothelial"
        df.loc[(df['Column Y']== "cell#2"), 'Column Y'] = "muscle"
    else:
        pass
```

My code does above does not work, the condition for rows=='FIRST' applies throughout the dataframe, and ignores the condition for rows=='SECOND". Please help.

EXPECTED OUTCOME:

```
Column X            Column Y        
    FIRST               epithelial
    FIRST               A
    FIRST               nerve
    FIRST               C
    SECOND              N
    SECOND              V
    SECOND              endothelial
    SECOND              muscle
```

OUTPUT for my above code (which is incorrect):

```
Column X            Column Y        
    FIRST               epithelial
    FIRST               A
    FIRST               nerve
    FIRST               C
    SECOND              N
    SECOND              V
    SECOND              epithelial
    SECOND              nerve
```

The last two rows in Column Y should be "endothelial" and "muscle", not "epithelial" and "nerve"

Comment: Your dataframe only has columns X and Y. What are columns A and B you're mentioning?

Comment: @nnnmmm thanks for catching the error. I meant to say Column Y, not Column B. I have made the edit.

Comment: It still says 'If Column A is "FIRST"' and similarly for B below that.

Comment: @nnnmmm, my apologies. it looks good now.

Comment: Ah, okay. I still don't fully understand your goal – maybe you can show us how your example DataFrame should look after the operation? By the way, I think the indentation in your code is not right (`elif` is on the same level as `for`).

Comment: @nnnmmm sorry I was not very clear on my previous question. I have added "Expected Dataframe" , and the dataframe I am getting from my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way. Note that no loops are required. Many `pandas` operations are vectorised for ease and performance.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['FIRST', 'cell#1'], ['FIRST', 'A'],
                   ['FIRST', 'cell#2'], ['FIRST', 'C'],
                   ['SECOND', 'N'], ['SECOND', 'V'],
                   ['SECOND', 'cell#1'], ['SECOND', 'cell#2']],
                  columns=['X', 'Y'])

df.loc[(df.X == 'FIRST') & (df.Y == 'cell#1'), 'Y'] = 'epithelial'
df.loc[(df.X == 'FIRST') & (df.Y == 'cell#2'), 'Y'] = 'nerve'
df.loc[(df.X == 'SECOND') & (df.Y == 'cell#1'), 'Y'] = 'endothelial'
df.loc[(df.X == 'SECOND') & (df.Y == 'cell#2'), 'Y'] = 'muscle'

#         X            Y
# 0   FIRST   epithelial
# 1   FIRST            A
# 2   FIRST        nerve
# 3   FIRST            C
# 4  SECOND            N
# 5  SECOND            V
# 6  SECOND  endothelial
# 7  SECOND       muscle
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a go at this to learn more about [grouping in Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) myself and was surprised that I could not find an elegant way to do this.

What I came up with is:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Column X': ['FIRST', 'FIRST', 'FIRST', 'FIRST', 'SECOND', 'SECOND', 'SECOND', 'SECOND'], 'Column Y': ['cell#1', 'A', 'cell#2', 'C', 'N', 'V', 'cell#1', 'cell#2']})

def f(group):
    y = group['Column Y']
    key = group['Column X'].iloc[0]
    if key == 'FIRST':
        y[y == 'cell#1'] = 'epithelial'
        y[y == 'cell#2'] = 'nerve'
    elif key == 'SECOND':
        y[y == 'cell#1'] = 'endothelial'
        y[y == 'cell#2'] = 'muscle'
    return group

df.groupby('Column X').apply(f)
```

but this requires getting the key from the grouped-by column *again*, where it would be simpler to have it be passed to `f`.